# Drop down box selection mutes/disables a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and HTML5 to create a web form. There's a section of the form where the user can select his "Method of delivery" via a drop-down box. The values are: Shop Pick-Up, FedEx, and Null. If the user selects FedEx, he shall then enter in his mailing address in the textarea titled "Shipping Address". However, since we do not need his mailing address if he selects "Shop Pick-Up" or "Null", is there a way to mute or grey-out the text box and only have it be writable if he selects "FedEx"?

Looking for ideas on how to approach this scenario.

My HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-3">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="delivery">Method of delivery</label>
        <select id="delivery" name="delivery" class="form-control input-lg" tabindex="17">
            <option value="options" selected disabled>-Select-</option>
            <option value="Shop Pick-Up">Shop Pick-Up</option>
            <option value="FedEx">FedEx</option>
            <option value="null">Null</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="shippingAddress">Shipping Address</label>
    <textarea name="shippingAddress" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="" tabindex="18"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have tried?? share your code

Comment: You can use a show/hide for the textarea based in the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the change event and update the text box based on the selected value.

```
$('#delivery').on('change', function(e){
    if($(this).val() == 'FedEx') 
        $('#shippingAddress').prop('disabled', false);
    else 
        $('#shippingAddress').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: This version worked on all browsers (IE7, IE8) for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options for dealing with non-required fields. The simplest option would be to add the attribute `disabled` to the textarea if they choose fedEx.

http://jsfiddle.net/dy4r3/

Your other option is to hide the non-required fields using `$.fn.hide()` and `$.fn.show()`

http://jsfiddle.net/ANKXA/

You can obviously expand on these solutions to make them a bit more elegant, but this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! I tried the first solution and it works, HOWEVER, since a generic 'textarea' is selected, it also happens to disable all the other textareas in the form simultaneously. I'd have to give shipping 'textarea' a unique ID, right? Thanks.

Comment: Yep! Adding an id to the text area should solve your problem.

Comment: David, I implemented your solution and then saw it works good in modern browsers, but the textarea did not re-enable after it was disabled in IE8. Can you confirm IE8 works for you? I guess that's IF you can get a copy of IE8...

Comment: It looks like IE8 does not work with the `:disabled` selector. A workaround would be to apply similar CSS formatting and disallow typing. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp

Comment: The solutoin posted by 'script shiva' above worked good for me in IE7/8 and it also still used the 'disabled' selector. Perhaps there's another reason why your version did not work. However, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Give the `shippingAddress` element an `id` (it should have one for the label `for`)

Then you can set the disabled attribute when the select box changes

```
$('#delivery').change(function(){
   $('#shippingAddress').prop('disabled', !($(this).val() == "FedEx"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` property of textarea can help you here.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/E2MsG/)

But showing and hiding would be better.

But there showing and hiding will make your form shake so apply some animation to avoid that or go with this approch but this approch also has some flaws as the user is nt directly clear when he will be allowed to enter the address.

I prefer going by show and hide as it is easy and informative.

[**Here is demo with show and hide**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/E2MsG/2/)